# Parse Json contains no array in c#

Tags: c#, json

I'm call an API that returns the following json

```
{
  "services":{
     "Home":{
        "Homecall":{
           "id":"10"
        },
        "Two Day":{
           "id":"11"
        },
        "Three Day":{
           "id":"12"
        }
     }
  }
}
```

What would be the best possible way to parse this so it returns 'Home' as a unqiue variable,
"homecall","Two day" and "three day" along with their ID in c#?

Comment: There are no arrays in this JSON string. `Home` is a dictionary/object with attributes named `HomeCall`, `Two Day`, `Three Day`. You can deserialize it to `Dictionary<string,Whatever>`

Comment: The api isn't returning any array in the JSON string, this is what has stumped me

Comment: Use `Dictionary<string,Whatever>` as `Home`'s type. Unless you want even `services` to be a dictionary. What does this JSON document contain? And what do you want to do with its contents?

Comment: You are the developer of the mentioned API and can change the implementation so you actually get an array?

Comment: Panagiotis, once im able to get this keys they'll be passed into a sql. I'll give your dictionary method a go.

Comment: Ralf, I am not the developer of the mentioned api

Comment: What is your expected output. Please post a datastructure, not some description ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try something like this

```cs
HomeClass home = new HomeClass
{
    Home = ((JObject)JObject.Parse(json)["services"]["Home"]).Properties()
        .Select(h => new MyClass { Name = h.Name, Id = Convert.ToInt64(h.Value["id"]) })
        .ToList()
};

public class HomeClass
{
    public List<MyClass> Home { get; set; }
}
public class MyClass
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

output in a json format

```cs
{
  "Home": [
    {
      "Id": 10,
      "Name": "Homecall"
    },
    {
      "Id": 11,
      "Name": "Two Day"
    },
    {
      "Id": 12,
      "Name": "Three Day"
    }
  ]
}
```